# Templated QDataStream operator<< for enumerations

Tags: c++, qt

Following various answers on this site, I tried to define my own template function to write any enumeration value into a QDataStream.

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value>>
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream& stream, T enumValue)
{
    stream << static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(enumValue);
    return stream;
}

enum class MyEnum_e : int16_t{};

QDataStream stream;
MyEnum_e value;
stream << value; // Doesn't work
```

But I can't get to make it work. Compilation fails with following message:

> no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'QDataStream' and
>   'MyEnum_e') stream << value;

Defining the function for each individual enumeration I have works as expected. Am I using `enable_if` wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `enable_if_t` to be the default value for a template parameter.

```
template <typename T, typename U=std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value>>
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream& stream, T enumValue)
{
    stream << static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(enumValue);
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: Just a question, why is the `U=` needed? It's odd as it's not used within the function body. Without, it fails with error `illegal type for non-type template parameter`

Comment: @DrumM When `T` is in fact an enumeration type, `std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value>` evaluates to the type `void`.  Without `U=`, this would be parsed as an attempt to declare a non-type template parameter (one that accepts a compile-time value instead of a type) of type `void` - but that's illegal since there are no values of type `void`.  The `U=` means we're instead declaring a type parameter, and the default argument for that type is the `enable_if_t` thing, which is permitted to be `void`.

Comment: @DrumM Another valid approach is `template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value>* = nullptr>`.  The `*` makes the type of the non-type template parameter `void*` instead of `void`, and that is a valid type.  And then we want to supply a default value for that parameter since there's no way for the compiler to automatically deduce it, so we just add `= nullptr`.

Comment: thanks for the info! This 2nd template parameter (`U`) is only used to make sure the template is only executed when an it's of type `enum`? Than I get it I think ;-)

Comment: @DrumM Right - though more technically, it makes sure the template does not produce a viable candidate function for overload resolution at compile time. Execution is more a run time thing.  This is called an SFINAE technique - Substitution Failure Is Not An Error.  Luckily, in C++20 we won't need such tricks: we'll simply write `template <typename T> requires std::is_enum_v<T>`, or even just `template <Enum T>` if `Enum` has been defined as a concept.

Comment: Yeah, compile time, absolutely ;-) Thanks for the nice info!

Comment: Another question, why can I not define the same function with the opposite template paramter: `template <typename T, typename U=std::enable_if_t<!std::is_enum<T>::value>>`. It says: cannot redefine default template parameter

Answer (score 2):

Since I found this while trying to stream an `enum Type : quint8 {...}` to & from `QSettings`, here's both ways for completeness.

```cpp
template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream& stream, const T &enumValue)
{
    return stream << static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(enumValue);
}

template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream& stream, T &enumValue)
{
    std::underlying_type_t<T> val;
    stream >> val;
    enumValue = static_cast<T>(val);
    return stream;
}
```

Also for `QSettings` the `enum` type AND the stream operators must be registered in Qt meta object system.  Enums are registered with the `Q_ENUM()` (in `QObject` or `Q_GADGET`) or `Q_ENUM_NS()` (in namespaces), or with `QT_DECLARE_METATYPE()` in other cases. The stream operators need to be registered separately with `qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<Type>("Type")`.  Also note that for `QFlags` there are already streaming operators defined, but AFAIK they still need to be registered with `qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators` to be streamed automatically.

**UPDATE:**
MSVC17 with C++14 didn't like my code above, so based on @DrumM's answer, here's what works for me now with that, MinGW 7.3, gcc 6.3 & 7.3:

```cpp
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, QDataStream&>::type
operator<<(QDataStream& stream, const T &enumValue)
{
    return stream << static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(enumValue);
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, QDataStream&>::type
operator>>(QDataStream& stream, T &enumValue)
{
    std::underlying_type_t<T> val;
    stream >> val;
    enumValue = static_cast<T>(val);
    return stream;
}

// ... later
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<MyScope::MyEnum>("MyScope::MyEnum");
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution [from aschepler above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42869036/2522849) is C++14. The following solutions work both for C++11.

<s>**1. Based on aschepler's answer:**</s>

```
template <typename T, typename U=std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>>
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream& stream, T enumValue)
{
    using underlying_type_t = typename std::underlying_type<T>::type;
    stream << static_cast<underlying_type_t>(enumValue);
    return stream;
}
```

See here that `enable_if_t` is not needed here, `enable_if` is sufficient.

Don't use this solution when using C++11 as mentioned by aschepler in his first comment.

**2. The next solution is based using the return type**

Return type?? Yes, you could expect to use `enable_if` on the the argument, but it's not applicable to operator overloads: See at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

> std::enable_if can be used as an additional function argument (not applicable to operator overloads), as a return type (not applicable to constructors and destructors), or as a class template or function template parameter.

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, QDataStream&>::type
operator<<(QDataStream& stream, T enumValue)
{
    using underlying_type_t = typename std::underlying_type<T>::type;
    stream << static_cast<underlying_type_t>(enumValue);
    return stream;
}
```

See that `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` is necessary here because the type needs to be returned.

Comment: Your operator in answer one never actually "disables" the specialization.  In http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c219f60d6b73e638 , the template operator unfortunately matches better than the intended `std::string` overload, despite the fact the argument is certainly not an enum.  `std::enable_if<false>` is a well-formed and complete type, that just happens not to have a member called `type`.  You need to get an actual failure for SFINAE to work, by using either `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` (C++11 or later) or `std::enable_if_t<...>::type` (C++14 or later).

Comment: Thanks @aschepler for this great comment! It makes sense!